# python text parsing to get the value based on coulmns

Tags: python

I have below python output in text format

```
words = r7.text
print(words)
print(type(words))

READ_P1  index1 - - -
WRITE_P1 index1 - - -
READ_p2  index2 - - -
WRITE_p2 index2 - - -
<class 'str'>
```

I want to find the index(1/2) where it is not READ_P1 and WRITE_P1, so my expected o/p should be index2,
what is the better way to achieve this.
Also READ_p2 and Write_P2 should have same value in this case index2.

Comment: what index is (1/2), index should be an int? I'm not sure what you asking here

Comment: sorry, I want to find either index1 or index2 , depending on 1st coulmn is either READ_p2 or write_p2 but the value of READ_p2 or write_p2 should be same i.e. index2

Comment: have you tried using `pandas` for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Iterate over the lines in the file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and keep or discard the lines that match your criteria.

- [Split each line on whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- use [indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to extract the columns you care about

Answer (score 0):

I have coded as below

```
for line in words.splitlines():
    if line.startswith("READ_STG"):
        a = (line.split()[1])
        print(a)

    if line.startswith("WRITE_STG"):
        b = (line.split()[1])
        print(b)
```

It print results like below

index2
index2

I want to make sure, both these values are matching before making further decision. but I can't compare a and b here.